# How to resolve:ssm in AWS::Serverless::Api DomainConfiguration BasePath?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless, aws-ssm

```
Resources:
  wwwResumeApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: prod
      Domain:
        BasePath:
          - '{{resolve:ssm:/www_resume/domain/api_base_path:1}}'
        DomainName: '{{resolve:ssm:/www_resume/domain/api_domain_name:1}}'
```

I have trouble resolving the ssm parameter in BasePath. Everything else works just fine. From the documentation, BasePath expects a List. I am not sure if that is the problem of resolving ssm. Thank you in advance, guys!

Comment: since you are using as string here `ssm:/www_resume/domain/api_base_path` should be as string. can you show what type and values you have in ssm?

Answer (score 0):

Base Path ssm as type `string`:

[image]

it will be as string within array:

```
        BasePath:
          - "{{resolve:ssm:/test/basepath:1}}"
        DomainName: "{{resolve:ssm:/test/domain:2}}"
```

If Base Path ssm is of type `StringList`

[image]

It will be used as array

```
    BasePath: "{{resolve:ssm:/test/basepathlist:1}}"
    DomainName: "{{resolve:ssm:/test/domain:2}}"
```